# inserting information into a multidimensional array after it has been created in php

Tags: php

I posted about this in another post regarding how to create a multidimensional array from records returned from SQL because I am returning repetitive information after hearing some suggestions I came to this solution which returns what I need but isn't returning all the information which should be inside of the sub array.  I had the following rows returned from the Database

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

        [iSaleID] => 5027347
        [userID] => 123
        [qty] => 1.0
        [price] => 20.00
        [item] => Cheese

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [iSaleID] => 5027347
        [userID] => 123
        [qty] => 2.0
        [price] => 10.00
        [item] => Milk
    )
```

I wanted to achieve this:

```
 Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [iSaleID] => 5027347
            [userID] => 123
            [items] => Array (
                  [0] => Array
                      (
                        [description] => Cheese
                        [qty] => 1.0
                        [price] => 20.00
                      )
                  [1] => Array
                      (
                        [description] => Milk
                        [qty] => 2.0
                        [price] => 10.00
                      )
                  )
             )
        )
...
```

not sure if my brackets are correct but I was attempting to create this so I did the following:

```
    $sql = "storedProcedure";
    $query= $con->query($sql);
    $results =  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $orderCnt = 0;
    $groupOrders = array();
    $lastSaleID = null;
    if(count($results) > 0){
        foreach($results as $order){
            if($order['iSaleID'] != $lastSaleID ){
                $groupOrders[$orderCnt]['id'] = $order['iSaleID'];
                $groupOrders[$orderCnt]['userID'] = $order['userID'];

                $groupOrders[$orderCnt]['items'][] = array('desc' => $order['desc'], 'qty' => $order['qty'] );

                $orderCnt++;
                $lastSaleID = $order['iSaleID'];

            }

        }
    }
```

This returns the saleID, the user ID only once for each customer (which is what I want) but only returns the first item they ordered. I assume it's because since the saleID is equal to the $lastSaleID then it skips the rest of the rows with the same sale ID, however I have tried putting `$groupOrders[$orderCnt]['items'][] = array('desc' => $order['desc'], 'qty' => $order['qty'] );` outside of the IF statement but that doesn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Had to change a few variable names in the array, as your example data does not fit your variables in the code example:

```
        $results = [
            [
                'iSaleId' => 5027347,
                'userId' => 123,
                'qty' => 1.0,
                'price' => 20.00,
                'item' => 'Cheese',
            ],
            [
                'iSaleId' => 5027347,
                'userId' => 123,
                'qty' => 2.0,
                'price' => 10.00,
                'item' => 'Milk',
            ],
        ];

        $orderCnt = 0;
        $groupOrders = [];
        if(count($results) > 0) {
            foreach($results as $order){
                if (!isset($groupOrders[$order['iSaleId']])) {
                    $groupOrders[$order['iSaleId']] = [
                        'id' => $order['iSaleId'],
                        'userId' => $order['userId'],
                        'items' => [],
                    ];
                    $orderCnt++;
                }
                $groupOrders[$order['iSaleId']]['items'][] = [
                    'desc' => $order['item'],
                    'qty' => $order['qty'],
                ];
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would I compare if the previous saleID is the same or different than the current one? I am returning multiple records with the same data for iSaleID abd UserID but the only difference is the Item so I want to make sure all items are get placed inside the items array of the iSaleID they pertain to.

Comment: Never mind I see what you did, you used the SaleID to check if it was the same. It works! I appreciate it my friend.